# Why are U+1CBB and U+1CBC invisible on Windows?

Tags: windows, unicode

If you're using Chrome on Windows, the characters "᲻" (U+1CBB) and "᲼" (U+1CBC) should appear invisible. (Firefox replaces unknown characters with their code points.) Why is that?

The [Unicode Standard](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1C90.pdf) doesn't define any characters for those code points, so why isn't Windows rendering them like any other unassigned code points ("԰")?

**Edit:** In MS Word, they look like question marks enclosed by squares, while other unassigned code points look like squares.

Comment: Related: [How do web browsers implement font fallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241764/how-do-web-browsers-implement-font-fallback)